# Mi consulta no trae los registros correctos C# .NET Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

tengo un problema al momento de traer lo datos de una tabla, aqui esta es el código:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var UserId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            var tickets = context.Tickets
                .Include(x => x.StatusTicket)
                .Include(x => x.AppUser.Person)
                .Include(x => x.Asset)
                .Include(x => x.TypeProblem)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.TypeProblemSolutions)
                .Where(x => x.State == true && x.UserId == UserId);


            return View(await tickets.ToListAsync());
        }
```

en aquí lo que quiero es traer los ticket que el usuario a generado y que me muestre también datos extras que se traen con las relaciones entre las tablas.
para explicar mejor voy a mostrar como esta mi tabla StatusTicket:
[[image: Tabla StatusTicket1]

bueno el problema es que siempre me muestra que los tickets están en Pendiente cuando algunos de ellos tienen el ID de StatusTicket en 2 como mostrare en esta imagen:
[image: El ID es 2 en StatusTicketID]

pero el problema es que cuando quiero mostrar los datos me muestra el dato de pendiente y también es por que jala ese dato, a pesar de que el id en el Ticket es 2:

[image: muestra de que StatusTicketId no coincide con el ID de StatusTicket]

y el ticket en la base de datos esta con el 2 en TicketStatusId, la verdad no entiendo por que no esta jalando el estado correcto.

Comment: Que loco, haber muestra las clases `Ticket` y `StatusTicket`, otra cosa que podria ayudar es lo que está dentro de `OnModelCreating` del context

Comment: oh gracias ya encontré el problema, mientras copiaba el código del modelo de ticket me di cuenta que estaba escrito otra clase en la relación de ForeingKey, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

ya encontre el problema, era que en el modelo de ticket el foreing key estaba apuntando a otra variable:

```
//llave foranea StatusTicket
  [Column(Order = 5)]
  [Display(Name = "Estado")]
  public int? StatusTicketId { get; set; } = 1;
  [ForeignKey("TypeProblemId")]
  public virtual StatusTicket StatusTicket { get; set; }
//Fin llave foranea
```

en [ForeignKey] estaba "TypeProblemId" cuando debería ir "StatusTicketId", asi que jalaba el Id de TypeProblemId de ticket que era 1 y por eso es que jalaba ese registro de StatusTicket.